# Trying to access ActiveMQ service in a minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns, port, activemq-classic, minikube

In a minikube test environment I have the following deployment/service (spun up in ArgoProj, so the template is slightly different) defined for ActiveMQ (version 5.14.5):

```
  - name: amq-server-d
    resource:
      action: create
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: amq
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: amq
              track: stable
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: amq
                track: stable
            spec:
              containers:
              - image: gms/activemq
                imagePullPolicy: Never
                name: amq
                ports:
                - containerPort: 61616
                - containerPort: 8161
                volumeMounts:
                - name: test-data
                  mountPath: /opt/activemq/data
                  readOnly: false  
                - name: test-conf
                  mountPath: /opt/activemq/conf
                  readOnly: false  
              volumes:
              - name: test-data
                hostPath:
                  path:   /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/data/adapt/amq/data  
              - name: test-conf
                hostPath:
                  path:  /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/data/adapt/amq/conf  


 - name: amq-server-s
    resource:
      action: create
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: amq
          namespace: default
          labels:
            app: amq
        spec:
          selector:
            app: amq
          ports:
          - name: test1
            protocol: TCP
            port: 61616
            targetPort: 61616
          - name: test2
            protocol: TCP
            port: 8161
            targetPort: 8161
```

The docker image works fine on its own and is defined as:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ENV ACTIVEMQ_VERSION 5.14.5
ENV ACTIVEMQ apache-activemq-$ACTIVEMQ_VERSION
ENV ACTIVEMQ_TCP=61616 ACTIVEMQ_AMQP=5672 ACTIVEMQ_STOMP=61613 ACTIVEMQ_MQTT=1883 ACTIVEMQ_WS=61614 ACTIVEMQ_UI=8161

ENV ACTIVEMQ_HOME /opt/activemq

RUN set -x && \
    curl -s -S https://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/$ACTIVEMQ_VERSION/$ACTIVEMQ-bin.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /opt && \
    ln -s /opt/$ACTIVEMQ $ACTIVEMQ_HOME && \
    useradd -r -M -d $ACTIVEMQ_HOME activemq && \
    chown -R activemq:activemq /opt/$ACTIVEMQ && \
    chown -h activemq:activemq $ACTIVEMQ_HOME

USER activemq

WORKDIR $ACTIVEMQ_HOME
EXPOSE $ACTIVEMQ_TCP $ACTIVEMQ_AMQP $ACTIVEMQ_STOMP $ACTIVEMQ_MQTT $ACTIVEMQ_WS $ACTIVEMQ_UI

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/activemq console"]
```

These work fine and show up as services and deployments:

```
D20181472:nlp-adapt-kube gms$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE   SELECTOR
amq          ClusterIP   10.111.0.111   <none>        61616/TCP,8161/TCP   2s    app=amq
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP              24h   <none>


D20181472:nlp-adapt-kube gms$ kubectl get deploy -o wide
NAME   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES         SELECTOR
amq    0/1     1            0           33s   amq          gms/activemq   app=amq,track=stable
```

And within the cluster, I can access the service by its name and namespace, ala:

```
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
dnstools# nslookup amq.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   amq.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.111.0.111
```

However, if I try curl to access the tcp protocol port 61616 (used by ActiveMQ for remote connections, which I believe is enabled by default), I get a time out:

```
dnstools# curl amq.default:61616
curl: (7) Failed to connect to amq.default port 61616: Operation timed out
```

I tested `curl` on the kubernetes cluster itself, and it is returning a response:

```
dnstools# curl -k -d 'body=message' https://10.96.0.1:443
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot post path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
```

AFAIK, there should not be any firewall rules enabled within minikube that would need to be dealt with for AMQ, so I'm not really sure why this isn't working. I've also tried using `NodePorts` for the AMQ service, but that didn't help. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: The problem lies in `kubectl get deploy`'s output: AVAILABLE=0. There are no pods in ready state. Check them with `kubectl describe`.

Comment: Sure enough, something went wrong: 
`D20181472:nlp-adapt-kube gms$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
amq-76ccdc4bb-f6sqn             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   17         5h50m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Laszlo Valko, it appears the pod did not start due to a permissions error:

```
D20181472:nlp-adapt-kube gms$ kubectl logs amq-76ccdc4bb-mbkml
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid
bin/activemq: 484: bin/activemq: cannot create /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid: Permission denied
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_181 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=58715k  max=932352k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/conf:/opt/activemq/../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq/data
Extensions classpath:
  [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/activemq/data/activemq.log (Permission denied)
```

Set to run as root, and now everything is functional:

```
dnstools# curl -o amq.default:61616
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
dnstools# curl  amq.default:61616
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
dnstools# curl  amq.default:61616 --output test.out
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   387    0   387    0     0  35181      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 38700
dnstools# cat test.out
ActiveMQ
         m
          TcpNoDelayEnabledSizePrefixDisabled   CacheSize
                                                         ProviderName  ActiveMQStackTraceEnabledPlatformDetails HJVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Linux, 4.15.0, amd64
                                                                                                                                                                                         CacheEnabledTightEncodingEnabled
                          MaxFrameSize@MaxInactivityDurationu0 MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay'ProviderVersion 5.14.5dnstools#


D20181472:nlp-adapt-kube gms$ kubectl logs amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt
INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java'
bin/activemq: 1: bin/activemq: ps: not found
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_181 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=58715k  max=932352k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/conf:/opt/activemq/../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq/data
Extensions classpath:
  [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5f2108b5: startup date [Sun Jan 27 02:57:49 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb]
 INFO | KahaDB is version 6
 INFO | Recovering from the journal @1:503
 INFO | Recovery replayed 147 operations from the journal in 0.115 seconds.
 INFO | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt-46331-1548557870872-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector amqp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector mqtt started
 WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e44b638{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
 INFO | Listening for connections at ws://amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector ws started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:amq-5bcc4fdfc5-8h7tt-46331-1548557870872-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
 INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
 WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://172.17.0.2:37578 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
 WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://172.17.0.2:37848 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
 WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://172.17.0.2:38082 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
```